# segmentation fault while calling base class constructor in derived class

Tags: c++

i'm getting a segmentation fault when i call the base class constructor from the derived class in c++ .i'm using the below code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A {
protected:
    int x;

public:
    A()
    {
        x = 10;
        cout << "value of X in A is" << x << "\n";
    }
};
class B : A {
private:
    int z;

public:
    B()
    {
        A::A();
        z = 20;
        cout << "value of z in B is" << z << "\n";
    }
};
int main()
{
    B* logger;
    logger = new B;
}
```

while building i have used the -fpermisson option to build this code else it was showing the below error.

```
main.cpp: In constructor ‘B::B()’:
main.cpp:19:7: error: cannot call constructor ‘B::A’ directly [-fpermissive]
  A::A();
       ^
main.cpp:19:7: note: for a function-style cast, remove the redundant ‘::A’
```

when i try to run this code i'm getting a segmentation fault. To understand the issue i did some debugging and could see that when i try to create the object of B the constructor of A getting called indefinitely that create the segmentation fault(i think so).
I'm not that expert in C++ please help me to understand what i did wrong here. i'm using linux environment to test this.

Comment: your code is invalid C++ as your error shows. So what is the purpose of understanding invalid C++ code?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i was just trying to understand whether a base class constructor could directly call from the derived class. the same code was working in visual cpp.

Answer (score 4):

You can't call a constructor directly like this:

```
A::A();  // error
```

Using additional flags to produce a program is fine, except that you can't expect the program to work.

If you want to call a base class constructor, you can do it in the member initializer list:

```
B() : A()
{
    z=20;
    cout<<"value of z in B is"<<z<<"\n";
}
```

In this case, it's not necessary because the default constructor will get called anyway.

Comment: thank you for the response. i understood that it is an issue from my coding. just for curiosity any insight why the constructor A is getting calling indefinity when i use the above code.

Comment: Not really, there's not enough information to figure that out. It depends on a *lot* of things.

Comment: ok. i did try the same code in visual cpp and could see that it is working there. but not sure why it is showing different behaviour in different environment .

Comment: Don't worry about it :) Understanding how c++ works can be a little difficult, but trying to understand how it doesn't work is much harder.

Comment: @user8759451 what you have is invalid C++ code. You will never see this code again, you will never write this code again. I say it again: it's not valid C++ code! The fact that it compiles on some compilers with some flags enabled is maybe just a backwards compatibility with some historical non-standard ancient implementation. There is no use in spending time and energy on this code.